# /Public_html/Wp-Includes/Class-Wp-Hook.Php On Line 307 loader imageClose

Tags: wordpress

[enter image description here][1]

Warning: Call_user_func_array() Expects Parameter 1 To Be A Valid Callback, Function 'Feed' Not Found Or Invalid Function Name In /Home/Hkrpvloo/Public_html/Wp-Includes/Class-Wp-Hook.Php On Line 307

```
/**
 * Calls the callback functions that have been added to a filter hook.
 *
 * @since 4.7.0
 *
 * @param mixed $value The value to filter.
 * @param array $args  Additional parameters to pass to the callback functions.
 *                     This array is expected to include $value at index 0.
 * @return mixed The filtered value after all hooked functions are applied to it.
 */
public function apply_filters( $value, $args ) {
    if ( ! $this->callbacks ) {
        return $value;
    }

    $nesting_level = $this->nesting_level++;

    $this->iterations[ $nesting_level ] = array_keys( $this->callbacks );
    $num_args                           = count( $args );

    do {
        $this->current_priority[ $nesting_level ] = current( $this->iterations[ $nesting_level ] );
        $priority                                 = $this->current_priority[ $nesting_level ];

        foreach ( $this->callbacks[ $priority ] as $the_ ) {
            if ( ! $this->doing_action ) {
                $args[0] = $value;
            }

                        // Avoid the array_slice if possible.
        if ( $the_['accepted_args'] == 0 ) {
            $value = call_user_func_array( $the_['function'], array() );
        } elseif ( $the_['accepted_args'] >= $num_args ) {
            $value = call_user_func_array( $the_['function'], $args );
        } else {
            $value = call_user_func_array( $the_['function'], array_slice( $args, 0, (int)$the_['accepted_args'] ) );
        }
    }
} while ( false !== next( $this->iterations[ $nesting_level ] ) );

unset( $this->iterations[ $nesting_level ] );
unset( $this->current_priority[ $nesting_level ] );
```

[enter image description here][2]
$this->nesting_level--;

```
return $value;
```

}